# Facebook tab that allows sending invitations

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I'm trying to make a Facebook tab that has the option to invite multiple friends. This I have achieved very easily with the Facebook API

My problem is the URL that is sent in the request. The url of my tab is the following type:
https://www.facebook.com/my_fan_page/app_id_app

But the invitation redirected to the following url:
http://apps.facebook.com/id_app/

This would not be a problem if not a cover tubiese prior to get "Likes" and in the second url there is no button "Like"

Is there any way that the invitation is sent to the first URL?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

When user accepts an invitation i.e. comes to your application canvas page by clicking on app request notification, Facebook sends comma separated ids in "request_ids" parameter.

Checking if request_ids is set or not you can redirect user to your required page tab url.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/notifications/) …?

> *“The logic is that, on web, if Canvas setting exists, we always show “Canvas URL + href”. If not, we show nothing.”*

It is currently not possible for notifications to point anywhere else then a canvas app.

But you can easily set up a canvas URL, and just place a minimal HTML document there that uses JavaScript to redirect to your page tab address.

Comment: Yes, my fault.

Properly, that's what I do, when they receive the invitation with javascript redirected to the url of the tab. In this way I lose my mobile device users because tabs are not available for mobile. I guess you can not have everything.

A greeting and thank you very much.